# Which install kit installs sqlcmd.exe?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd, ssdt

I recently had to uninstall Visual Studio 2012 and DTS, then install VS 2017 and DTS again. Afterwards, The directory containing `sqlcmd.exe` was not in my `PATH` variable. I installed the following.

```
vs_Professional-vs2017-15.9.41.exe
SSDT-Setup-ENU-vs2017-15.9.9.exe
```

Should either of these kits install `sqlcmd.exe`? If not, which tool will install it? I need one that will work with SQL Server 2012+.

Comment: To your actual question, I'm not sure if either of those installers also install sqlcmd. I normally suggest explicitly installing it via the [Command Line Utilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#download-the-latest-version-of-sqlcmd-utility) installer if you need it. Is there any reason you would not want to use the dedicated installer?

Comment: @AMtwo, yes, that did it. If you want to make this an answer, I will select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if either of those installers also install `sqlcmd`. Microsoft has shifted from "everything bundled together" types of installs to more modular installs.

I normally suggest explicitly installing it via the [Command Line Utilities installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#download-the-latest-version-of-sqlcmd-utility) if you need it.

Some things (like the full SQL Server database engine) still include `sqlcmd` as part of the install, so take note of which version of `sqlcmd` gets used if there are multiple versions installed. You can determine this by running `sqlcmd /?` and examining the output for version information:

```
C:\Users\AMtwo>sqlcmd /?
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 15.0.2000.5 NT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply download SQLCmd through [the following link](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142258) (for x64) and [this one](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142257) (for x86).
If your client is on linux you may want to check [that documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver15).

You just need [Windows Installer 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/what-s-new-in-windows-installer-5-0) and [Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) as pre-requisites.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#download-the-latest-version-of-sqlcmd-utility)